# How can configuration profiles installed by MDM update the device's keychain?

Tags: android, ios, security, configuration, mdm

I'm looking for a way to retrieve a license string from a 3rd party MDM (like XenMobile, AirWatch, Apps@Work, etc.) that would be included as a key/property inside a configuration profile.  This is not an in house or enterprise app, it's an app the customer downloads from the App Store, then wraps it using their MDM.  These MDMs install device policies and profiles on the device, but I've read in other posts these configuration profile keys aren't accessible programmatically by our app?

iOS: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html

Example: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/ConfigurationProfileExamples/ConfigurationProfileExamples.html

**Here are the steps that need to happen:**

1) company downloads new version of our app from the App Store via their MDM

2) the company updates something on their end with a license string (**what are all the possibilities here?**)

3) their MDM wraps our app and is deployed (by WorxHome, maybe AirWatch, Apps@Work) with the license key they updated in a place where our app will be able to read the license string when our app runs the first time.

4) Our app reads a config profile key, maybe a keychain item that was updated by the config profile, or any property we can access when the app launches that now contains the license we need to validate

This is all done so the user doesn't need to manually enter the license (or even know what the license is).  It really doesn't matter how it happens besides that the customer needs to enter the license somewhere on their end, and that string is accessible by our app on launch.  I mention the keychain (at least for iOS) in the title of this post since it seems like this might be the easiest way?

**This needs to happen on both iOS and Android so any insight into how either might work is helpful.**